# Replace Marker with XML text with BASH

Tags: xml, bash

I want to replace a Marker (like ###marker###) inside a file with XML text `(<networkConnector bla="blubb"/>...)`

The text i want to insert is already generated in my script and is stored in a variable ($CONNECTIONS)

Is there a simple way to do that with Bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using a perl script i found.

http://hellem.org/blog/index.php/2010/04/16/bash-insert-content-of-one-file-into-another-file?blog=6

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s/###marker###/$CONNECTIONS/g" file.txt
```

Comment: i tried that long ago. sed: -e expression #1, char 58: unknown option to `s'

Comment: perhaps your $CONNECTIONS contains 'funny' characters. Try something like `sed -i "s~###marker###~$CONNECTIONS~g" file.txt` assuming `~` doesn't occur. (otherwise, post the value of $CONNECTIONS you are testing with)

Comment: just noticed that stackoverflow deleted my example. Connections contains xml so of cause there are some letters that sed doesn't like (for example spaces). I solved my problem using a perl script i found. http://hellem.org/blog/index.php/2010/04/16/bash-insert-content-of-one-file-into-another-file?blog=6