# insert several strings into xml at a marker

Tags: python, xml, moodle, pystache

I would like to add a list of equations in a CSV to an xml doc for importing into moodle lms. Is there a way i can do this with python. along the lines of a mail merge. I have tried with libre office but the xml gets changed
i have tried the following links and more. 
thanks

[Replace Marker with XML text with BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187589/replace-marker-with-xml-text-with-bash)
[Add to origonal xml file from for loop in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449297/add-to-origonal-xml-file-from-for-loop-in-python)
[Replacing XML element in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437103/replacing-xml-element-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Question? 
i found that templating would provide the answer, and used pystache as it seemed really simple. Finally

```
import pystache
txt = open('pystachetempl.xml', 'r').read()
doc = open('results.xml', 'wb')

doc.write(pystache.render(txt, {
  "questionname": "expon frac neg",
  "latexquestion1": "frac{3{x}^{-3}}{{(3x)}^{2}}",
  "tans1": "1/(3*x^5)"
   }).encode('utf-8'))
```

i wasn't able to read the context from file and had to use the replacement values in the code to get it to work.